# Is Directory.EnumeratedDirectorties postponed before execution?

Tags: c#

I am using the following code

`var allFolderPaths = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(this.sourceFolder, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);`

The issue I am having , is during a foreach loop (iterating over the allFolderPaths variable as shown above), it is failing because the directory is not found.

Now, the following code is, by itself not looking at directories etc, it's just a string loop:

```
foreach (string folder in StringList)
{
       /dostuff 
}
```

However, when I update the code to use the allFolderPaths (As per the first example in this post)

```
foreach (string folder in allFolderPaths)
{
       /dostuff 
}
```

it fails due to "access to a path denied"!

So, does this mean the variable allFolderPaths is not actually 'assigned' at the point it is assigned to (if that makes any sense)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directory.EnumerateFiles() returns an IEnumerable<> which is 'executed' only when you actually enumerate the enumerable...(aka "lazy execution").

If you want to force the EnumerateFiles to execute right-away, you can add a .ToList() (aka "memoization").

Example:

```
  var allFolders = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(this.sourceFolder, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

The reason for the AccessDenied exception is that you're trying to enumerate a directory that you don't have permission to enumerate; Are you looking in 'My Documents' or similar?

Comment: Ha ha, you know your stuff; Yes, it is the My Documents folder which is causing the issue - this is why I'm trying to go through each folder, one at a time, see if I have permissions and if so, add it to a HavePermisionsList

Comment: Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: The problem folders are the 'fake' folders : viz 'My Pictures', 'My Music' etc. I've made a 'SafeEnumerateDirectory' function which will catch exceptions. Source here https://gist.github.com/3972045

Comment: Thank you for this - it's interesting to see that all solutions I've seen use the catch in a way to 'suppress' the error message and move to the next item in the iteration. It's supposed to be a bad practice but realistically it appears to be the only way which works!

Comment: You can get around the try/catch by using Interop with FindFirstFile(), FindNextFile() ... internally that's what Directory.EnumerateFiles is doing in any case. However, the speed increase is not worth it in this case, because you're really bound by IO time not CPU time.

Answer (score 1):

No, it means that your process is attempting to access a file/directory for which it does not have permission.

Answer (score 1):

The allFolderPaths variable in your code is of type `IEnumerable<string>`.  Which indeed means that you won't access the disk until you start enumerating it with a foreach loop.

A "Directory not found" exception in this context is pretty unlikely since its name was retrieved a millisecond ago.  But not entirely impossible, the file system can change on-the-fly as other processes access the disk.

An "Access denied" exception is highly likely, especially when you iterate the root directory of a drive.  The "System Volume Information" folder is not accessible even to an administrator.  You'll need to catch this exception and continue.  A good way to avoid them is to use DirectoryInfo.Attributes.  If the directory is Hidden and System then you almost always want to steer clear from such a directory.

Comment: This is what I thought I would have to avoid; it appears that try catch is not a good thing to do and should only be used more as a 'try - catch - attempt something else'... however, I can use the catch to just suppress the message and move on to the next directory! It would work for sure, but, is that what you mean?

Comment: You've got a basic choice between using try/catch and allowing another process on the machine to randomly crash your program.  The latter is never the wrong thing to do, you can blame the other process.